# Using the runif function to count occurrences using R

Tags: r

Let's say that the probability that an event occurs is 0.2. I would like to, for example for 50 times, count the amount of times that the event occurs, using the runif function in R.

Is this the correct way to do that? Because it's not really giving the expected outcomes.

`X <- 50`

`amount <- (runif(X)<0.2)`

or

`amount <- sum(runif(X)<0.2))`

Comment: What result are you getting? What result are you expecting?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's just review this line by line:

The following sets X, the number of trials, to 50.

```
X <- 50
```

Let's look at our choices:

```
amount <- (runif(X)<0.2)
```

This will return a vector of T/F values, each the result of a trial with True meaning the event occurs and False meaning the event does not occur.

```
amount <- sum(runif(X)<0.2))
```

Is like the previous  command but sums over the results. This counts the number of times the event occurs.

Comment: Thanks, I used both the first and second method in my code and both gave me strange answers, but since the second method is correct, the error in my code must lie elsewhere.

Answer (score 1):

Well, strange is something subjective -- random numbers can look strange but still be random. You can check whether your result is actually strange or not:

```
runs <- replicate(1000, sum(runif(50)<0.2))
mean(runs)  # I got 10.028
median(runs)  # should be exactly 10
```

Nothing strange here. (I would use `rbinom` instead of `runif` here but that shouldn't change much.)